# AAD authentication getting access token

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am trying to get an access token for powerbi users, following this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data-get-token

But I am getting an error at this line of code

```
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).Result.AccessToken;
```

Error:

clinetID is - cannot convert from 'string' to 'microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientcredential'

new Uri(redirectUri) = cannot convert from 'System.uri' to 'microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.User'

Code for getting access token:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Service
{
    public class PowerbiService
    {
        private static string token = string.Empty;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Get an authentication access token
            token = GetToken();

        }
        #region Get an authentication access token
        private static async Task<string> GetToken()
       {
        string clientID = "{Client_ID}";

            string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

           string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

           string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.net/common/";

           AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
           var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).Result.AccessToken;

           Console.WriteLine(token);
           Console.ReadLine();

           return token;
       }

       #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like already there is an issue with the sample please refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues/2287)

Comment: COuld you please tell me which auth flow you want to know?

Comment: Is that you run the code in console application?

Comment: @JimXu I am trying to run this in azure function.

Comment: @bippan According to the code your provide, you need to open a window to provide the username and password. But Azure function a non-interactive service, it cannot open a window for you. I suggest you  encode the username and password in your application  ; https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password.

Comment: @JimXu, there is no other way than to provide username and password, because azure functions act as a daemon or background service so it should not require a username and password to access. For example, as in the Google service account, there is no need for a username and password to access, with the client id and the token I am able to access.

Comment: @bippan According to your need, I suggest you use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). If you use the flow, you use client_id and client_secret to get token : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-with-service-principal